# How to archive trained PyTorch models?

Tags: data-science-model, pytorch, model-selection

Currently, I am working on my thesis which is built on `LSTM` networks and I am using `PyTorch` library. However I am struggling to solve the conceptual problem of archiving trained `models`.

To make the question more clear; I am saving models in a archicture that I can give this form `/models/model-with-loss-2.634221` as an example. But with this form, it is hard to determine which is which. I tried use more detailed form like `1-layered-100-epoch-128-batchsize-...-etc`, but it is also hard to read and determine.

What is your way that you think is most productive to handle such operation?

By the way I am not sure this is the correct network ask this question on, you can drop an comment if it is not.

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/68114/55122 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to give each model a unique identifier (e.g., a hash value or nickname). Then store all the metadata in another file.

Another option is using the PyTorch [torch-model-archiver](https://pytorch.org/serve/model-archiver.html) feature.